# Python 3: How to write a __iter__ method for derived class so that it extends on the behaviour of the base class' __iter__ method

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, iterable

Say I have a base class:

```
class Base:
    A = False
    B = ''
    C = ''

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 'a', self.A
        yield 'b', self.B
        yield 'c', self.C
```

And then a class that derives from this base:

```
class Data(Base):
    D = ''

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 'd', self.D
```

This ofcourse only creates a dictionary containing `{ 'd': <value> }` on `dict( Data() )`, when instance of data class if converted to `dict` type; because as I understand it the derived class `__iter__` method is effectively overwriting the base class `__iter__` method.

Then I tried to call base class method from the derived class overwritten method like we do in `__init__()` function:

```
def __iter__(self):
    super().__iter__()
    yield 'd', self.D
```

But the IDE flagged that as an error. Why does this not work? 
And how to define the derived iter method to extend on the already existing base class iter method, so that I only have to add yield for the added variables in derived class? Is manually writing out all the yields again in the derived class iter method, which is how for the moment I have implemented it, the only solution? Why?

```
class Data(Base):
    D = ''

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 'a', self.A
        yield 'b', self.B
        yield 'c', self.C
        yield 'd', self.D
```

Comment: Just a note: There are no dictionaries created here. Your iterators yield tuples that you could pass into a dict (ex. `dict(Base())` and `dict(Data())`), but that isn't the same thing.

Comment: @BaileyParker Yes that is what I meant. I pass instance into dict() so that I can then create a json of the data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't work because `super().__iter__()` is a generator and calling a generator in this context doesn't make sense. What you want to do is iterate over the things returned by that generator and yield them from your `__iter__` in `Data`:

Python 2:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for i in super().__iter__():
        yield i
    yield 'd', self.D
```

But in Python 3 this can be written more succinctly as:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield from super().__iter__()
    yield 'd', self.D
```

Comment: Your Python 2 example provides the opportunity to transform the value before re-yielding it, like yielding `str(i)` instead of `i` - which is what I'm looking for.  Is it possible to do the same using your Python 3 syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You must delegate to the base class:

```
In [1]: class Base:
   ...:     A = False
   ...:     B = ''
   ...:     C = ''
   ...:
   ...:     def __iter__(self):
   ...:         yield 'a', self.A
   ...:         yield 'b', self.B
   ...:         yield 'c', self.C
   ...:

In [2]: class Data(Base):
   ...:     D = ''
   ...:
   ...:     def __iter__(self):
   ...:         yield from super().__iter__()
   ...:         yield 'd', self.D
   ...:

In [3]: print(list(Data()))
[('a', False), ('b', ''), ('c', ''), ('d', '')]

In [4]: print(dict(Data()))
{'c': '', 'b': '', 'd': '', 'a': False}
```

Python 3 allows the `yield from` syntax, in Python 2 use:

```
class Base(object): # make sure to inherit from object for super to work
    A = False
    B = ''
    C = ''

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 'a', self.A
        yield 'b', self.B
        yield 'c', self.C

class Data(Base):
    D = ''

    def __iter__(self):
        for x in super(Data, self).__iter__():
            yield x
        yield 'd', self.D
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed code and result in your answer. Since Bailey Parker's answer also contains the reasoning I was looking for, I am going to accept that answer. I hope you don't mind.